# Detect if the user is resizing a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, static, textbox

I have some code that allows a textarea to be moved around:

```js
// Note that this code is paraphrased. It may not work exactly.
function createSelection(e) {
  if (dragging == false) {
    newSelection = document.createElement('textarea');
    newSelection.classList.add('resizeBox');
  
    newSelection.style.position = "absolute";
    newSelection.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    newSelection.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    newSelection.style.width = '0%';
    newSelection.style.height = '0%';
    newSelection.style.border = "dashed 2px orange";
    newSelection.style.outline = "0"

    startX = e.pageX;
    startY = e.pageY
    
    document.body.appendChild(newSelection);
    
    newSelection.addEventListener('mousedown', dragSelection);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', resizeSelection);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', finalizeSelection);
  }
}

function dragSelection(e) {
  var target = e.target
  dragging = true
  target.style.cursor = 'grabbing';

  // TODO: Make this box ontop of everything else
  let offsetX = e.offsetX;
  let offsetY = e.offsetY;
  
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveSelection);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragSelection);
  
  function moveSelection(e) {
    if (e.target.style.cursor == "nwse-resize") {
      return null;
    }
    console.log(2)
    target.style.left = (e.pageX - offsetX) + 'px';
    target.style.top = (e.pageY - offsetY) + 'px';
  }
  
  function stopDragSelection() {
    target.style.cursor = 'grab';
    dragging = false
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveSelection);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDragSelection);
  }
}

function resizeSelection(e) {
  var width = e.pageX - startX;
  var height = e.pageY - startY;

  newSelection.style.width = Math.abs(width) + 'px';
  newSelection.style.height = Math.abs(height) + 'px';
  newSelection.style.left = (width < 0 ? e.pageX : startX) + 'px';
  newSelection.style.top = (height < 0 ? e.pageY : startY) + 'px';
  newSelection.style.border = "dashed 2px orange";
}

function finalizeSelection(e) {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', resizeSelection);
  window.removeEventListener('mouseup', finalizeSelection);
}
```

This works fine, but when I try to resize the textbox, by clicking on the little icon in the bottom right corner, it moves it instead. How could I tell if the user is clicking on that icon?

I've tried to tell if the cursor is a certain icon:

```js
  if (e.target.style.cursor == "nwse-resize") {
    return null;
  }
```

but that didn't work.

I've also tried to see if the width and height of the textbox is being changed, but that doesn't work because it's not being resized, it's just being dragged.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To detect a resize action on the textarea, check the cursor position relative to its bottom-right corner in your code like this:

```
function dragSelection(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  dragging = true;
  target.style.cursor = 'grabbing';

  // Get the dimensions of the textarea
  var textareaRect = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  // Calculate the distance from the cursor to the bottom right corner
  var offsetX = textareaRect.width - (e.clientX - textareaRect.left);
  var offsetY = textareaRect.height - (e.clientY - textareaRect.top);
  
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveSelection);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDragSelection);
  
  function moveSelection(e) {
    // Check if the cursor is near the bottom right corner
    if (offsetX <= 10 && offsetY <= 10) {
      // Cursor is in the resize area
      resizeSelection(e);
    } else {
      // Cursor is outside the resize area, so move the textarea
      target.style.left = (e.pageX - offsetX) + 'px';
      target.style.top = (e.pageY - offsetY) + 'px';
    }
  }
  
  function stopDragSelection() {
    target.style.cursor = 'grab';
    dragging = false;
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', moveSelection);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDragSelection);
  }
}
```

Summarizing: calculate the cursor-to-bottom-right-corner distance, check if it's within 10 pixels. If so, then resize using resizeSelection, otherwise move the textarea. Adjust the threshold as needed.